# Intellij Idea : view test coverage on a maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, test-coverage

Is there a way to run all test in an root pom and collect test coverage in Intellij Idea ?

Comment: Do you mean a multi-module maven project?

Comment: Yes, I mean a pom with multiple sub-poms.

Comment: These days this is only in Ultimate

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Create a Run Configuration that will look for tests in the whole project. Make sure that you choose `All in package` and `In whole project` in the configurations dialog:

[image]

Make sure that you choose the `<default>` package in the `Choose Package` dialog.

[image]

Now you can select to run this configuration using `Run 'All in project' with Coverage`:

[image]

The result will be presented in a separate coverate window:

[image]

And you will also see the result in the `Project View` window for a fast overview:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Right click on the parent module (root pom), and select `Run 'All Tests' with Coverage`.

[image]

Comment: There is no such option when I right click on the root module. May be the problem is that this folder is not marked as source/test.

Comment: Works for me. Right-click the root directory where your `pom.xml` and `src` sit in.

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'Coverage' plugin, which may not be enabled by default.

Find it at `File->Settings->Plugins`.

This will enable the 'Run with Coverage' buttons and menu items.

A short official overview video is here: [Code Coverage by IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtu.be/yNYzZvyA2ik)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on ceilfors answer since it has slightly changed.

Right click on the test module -> `More Run/Debug` -> `Run 'Tests in ...' with Coverage`

This is with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Also the doc shows another way to do it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html